# Why my unbound service class dosen't work?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to create a table on a database using a `service unbound` to achieve this. But i get no response. The `service` start and when i check the database, there is no trace of it!
My class `unboundService`:

```
public class MyUnboundService extends Service {
    HttpClient httpClient = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("MY_UNBOUNDSERVICE", "onCreate()");
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Start service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("MY_UNBOUNDSERVICE", "onStartCommand(...)");

        String create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "name TEXT, forename TEXT)";

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("createTabell", create));
        new AsyncTaskTabell(this).execute(new Pair<>(nameValuePairs, httpClient));

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("MY_UNBOUNDSERVICE", "onDestroy(...)");
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Stopper service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and i am calling `MyUnboundService` from the mainActivity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyUnboundService.class);
            startService(intent);
```

what is simply wrong with my code? - Any help og suggestions are very appreciated, Thanks.
The AsyncTask class:

```
public class AsyncTaskTabell extends AsyncTask<Pair<List<NameValuePair>, HttpClient>, Void, String> {

    private Context context = null;

    public AsyncTaskTabell(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<List<NameValuePair>, HttpClient>... params) {

        Pair pair = params[0];

        List<NameValuePair> urlParams = (List<NameValuePair>)pair.first;
        HttpClient httpClient = (HttpClient)pair.second;
        try {
            String serverURL = MainActivity.address + MainActivity.stringCommands[MainActivity.SF_POS];
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverURL);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParams));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            }
            return "Wrong: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Intent i = new Intent("pos").putExtra("theResult", result);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not showing any code where you're creating a table in a database.

Comment: From `String create` and i send the parameters to my `servlet` using `AsyncTaskTabell`. This is what i want to do: create a table!

Comment: Do you see the stuff you log in onStartCommand() ?

Comment: What do you mean? - please explain clearly!

Comment: There's a Log.d() statement in onStartCommand(). When you start the Service, do you see the output in logcat?

Comment: yes, it shows `onStartCommand(...)` and after `onDestroy(...)`

Comment: Then presumably the issue is in AsyncTaskTabell which you are not showing

Comment: i edited my question and i show my `asyncTask class`.

Comment: And do you know what the result of the AsyncTask is? Do you have a receiver for the broadcast? Or can you log it?

Comment: This is the result from `AsyncTask`: `[ 04-18 23:20:12.685  1496: 1496 I/ConfigService ]`...no clue what it means?!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you registered your service in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file?
Try adding this line inside the `application` element:

```
<service android:enabled="true"
         android:name=".MyUnboundService"/>
```